# fullcalendar with qtip2 - How do I make the qtip scroll correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, qtip2

This works - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30rmwg4x/1/)

```
$("#FullCalendar").fullCalendar({
    timezone: false,
    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    eventLimit: true,
    events: [{
        title: 'event1',
        start: moment().startOf('day').add(8,'hours')
    }],
    eventAfterRender: function(event, element) {
        var $viewport = $(".fc-time-grid-container.fc-scroller");
        var qapi = $(element).qtip({
            content: "woo",
            hide: {
                event: false
            }
        }).qtip('api');
        $viewport.on("scroll", function () {
            qapi.reposition();
        });
        qapi.show();
        event.qapi = qapi;
    },
    eventDestroy: function( event, element, view ) {
        event.qapi.destroy();
    },
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    }
});
```

- Agenda view so the calendar can't show the whole day and needs a scrolling div
- [qTip](http://qtip2.com) on a [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) event
- Scroll event listener to call [`qApi.reposition`](http://qtip2.com/api#api-methods.reposition) so the qtip remains pointed at the event.

The problem is that it isn't hidden when you scroll down far enough:
[image: scrolling problem]

I found several places that say the solution is to set `position.container` as the scrolling div which should take care of this problem (and maybe the need for a scroll event listener too). But `position.container` only seems to break things for me.

None of these work: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/30rmwg4x/2/))

```
position: {
    //container: element.parent()
    //container: element
    container: $viewport
}
```

I've also tried using `position.viewport` and `position.target`.

Comment: Is that gif to annoying? Reverting one edit will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the element is visible after scrolling, and show/hide the qtip accordingly.

```
$viewport.on("scroll", function () {
            if(isScrolledIntoView(element[0])) {
                qapi.show();
                qapi.reposition();
            }
            else {
                qapi.hide();
            }
        });
```

[Check this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ynr0r0m/1/)

**Edit:** A nice way to check element visibility can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488073/2300466)

Comment: Hmm, I suppose this is one way of doing it. You should have this linked in your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling

Comment: @slicedtoad of course I'd have it linked, if your question is about checking element visibility. Just search for the implementation you want for the `isScrolledIntoView()` function.

Comment: I just mean that it should be linked in order to provide attribution as per cc by-sa: http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/